# Alternative for WinINet function (InternetCrackUrl)?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-runtime, wininet

I am looking for an alternative API of [InternetCrackUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from WinINet.h, so that I can use it for my WinRT store app.

I found there's a [mapping guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464945.aspx) mentioned Windows.Web.Http and XML HTTP Extended Request (IXMLHttpRequest2) could be alternatives, but after browsing the APIs I did not find anything similar to InternetCrackUrl().

Please share some pointers on alternatives that I can use. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`Windows::Foundation::Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.uri).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WinHttpRequest ActiveX object from winhttpcom.dll which uses winhttp.dll. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/iwinhttprequest-send

In Excel:
When using this within Excel VBA, you can add a reference to Microsoft WinHTTP Services.

```
Dim x As WinHttpRequest
Set x = New WinHttpRequest
x.Open "GET", sUrlAddress, True
x.Send
x.WaitForResponse
MsgBox x.ResponseText
Set x = Nothing
```